# How to use an icon as back button for UINaviationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller

Does anyone know how to use an icon instead of text for the UINavigationController back button?

[alt text http://www.img-hosting.de/bilder/24505iPhoneSimulator2png](http://www.img-hosting.de/bilder/24505iPhoneSimulator2png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UIBarItem *backBar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:yourImage style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBar;

[backBar release];
```

you can also use initWithCustomView if you need something more elaborate

Comment: I used that code but nothing happend neither for the current view nor for the next view - instead of yourImage I used [ UIImage imageNamed :  @"store.png"]

Comment: Your need to make sure you have an channel in the image:
<p>The alpha values in the source image are used to create the images—opaque values are ignored

Comment: This won't work with 3.0+. You simply get a plain back button if you set `backBarButtonItem` to be a UIBarButtonItem with a custom view or an image.